# AnimatedSize won't show animation while reducing container size, works only when size is increased

Tags: flutter, animation, containers

I have the following code that works fine while enlarging the size of the container. It shows the animation alright. But when it reduces to original size, it just collapses instead of easing.

```
class HomeScreen extends StatefulWidget {
const HomeScreen({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  _HomeScreenState createState() => _HomeScreenState();
 }

class _HomeScreenState extends State<HomeScreen> with TickerProviderStateMixin {
 double? screenWidth;
 double? screenHeight;

double? _height = 0;
double _width = 0;
bool _isExpanded = false;
Color _color = Colors.grey.withOpacity(0.75);

void _updateSize() {
setState(() {
  _isExpanded = !_isExpanded;
  _height = _isExpanded ? null : 0;
  //_isExpanded = !_isExpanded;
});
}

@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
screenWidth = MediaQuery.of(context).size.width;
screenHeight = MediaQuery.of(context).size.height;

return Scaffold(
  //backgroundColor: Colors.black87,
  body: Center(
    child: GestureDetector(
      onTap: () => _updateSize(),
      child: Container(
        //color: _color,
        child: AnimatedSize(
          vsync: this,
          duration: Duration(milliseconds: 500),
          curve: Curves.easeIn,
          child: Container(
            child: Container(
              padding: EdgeInsets.all(25),
              decoration: BoxDecoration(
                color: _color,
                borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(20),
              ),
              child: Steps(height: _height, width: _width),
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ),
    ),
   ),
   );
   }
  }

class Steps extends StatelessWidget {
const Steps({
 Key? key,
 this.height,
 this.width,
}) : super(key: key);

 final double? height;
 final double? width;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
  return Container(
  height: height,
  child: ListView.builder(
      padding: EdgeInsets.zero,
      shrinkWrap: true,
      itemBuilder: (context, index) => Column(
            children: [
              ListTile(
                dense: true,
                leading: Text('# ${index + 1}'),
                title: Text(
                  kRecipeSteps[index],
                  style: TextStyle(fontSize: 22, color: Colors.white),
                ),
              ),
              Divider(
                color: Colors.white,
                thickness: 1.0,
              ),
            ],
          ),
      itemCount: kRecipeSteps.length),
 );
 }
 }
```